# MedicalSciences.SE Moderation Strike

Tags: discussion, moderators

###### Update August 2nd, 2023:

After intense negotiations with representatives elected by the striking moderators, Stack Overflow, the operator of the Stack Exchange network, has agreed to a number of changes.

You can find details about the negotiations and changes here:
[Moderation strike: Results of negotiations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391847/moderation-strike-results-of-negotiations)

---

For those not aware, [moderators and curators from across the StackExchange network are ceasing their moderation activities](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/) in protest of recent policy changes by StackExchange. In particular, there is a new policy, part in public and frustratingly somewhat different and more restrictive in private, against removing content generated automatically by AI programs like ChatGPT. This policy was dropped without advanced discussion or warning and without consideration of feedback from moderators or the many community policies against this content, including [here](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1392/ban-chatgpt-and-ai-generated-answers-on-medicalsciences-se).

We feel that this content is likely to mislead users, and if posted in bulk will overwhelm the quality control measures (human voters) we have here. ChatGPT-generated content tends to be elegantly confabulated, in the sense that it typically takes a lot of extra effort to evaluate despite being so often incorrect. Additionally, posting this content is dishonest and breaks standards of attribution. Users posting AI-generated answers  are taking credit for content that they did not have a substantial role in creating and that they cannot vouch for.

All three moderators here are participating.

There are other posts on Meta Stack Exchange and Meta Stack Overflow that get into some more details:

[Moderation Strike: Stack Overflow, Inc. cannot consistently ignore, mistreat, and malign its volunteers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an)

[Stack Exchange is failing its community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389558/stack-exchange-is-failing-its-community)

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424979/what-has-happened-to-lead-moderators-to-consider-striking

and many other related posts, particularly on https://meta.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

Yesterday SE offered a new moderation policy regarding AI-generated content. Some moderators find this policy acceptable, including all the mods of MedSci, and have resumed moderating. However, there is no union and moderators are all acting independently. I don't know if all mods will find the policy acceptable, so I can only speak for the moderators here. We have ended our strike.

Answer (score 0):

The strike ended yesterday, on August 2nd. This was announced at the page linked in the first hyperlink in Bryan's post.

Comment: This is not really accurate. Striking mods act as individuals and the negotiations aren't binding on any of us.

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer if you think that's necessary. Medical Science mods have removed "on strike" from their usernames and I've seen Carey close a question.

Comment: Please see this: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5329/93303

Comment: That post represents an agreement among Academia moderators and doesn't apply to anyone else. Carey's answer and Ian's edit to the question here are more authoritative for this site.